# Can I force Siri to pronounce my app name differently?

Tags: ios, xcode, sirikit

I have a SiriKit extension for my iOS app and I want it to pronounce the app name differently. For the sake of this question let's say the app's name is 'POP'. While Siri pronounces it as the word 'pop', I want it to pronounce it as 'Pee Oh Pee'. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I have tried using the INAlternativeAppNames item in the plist but this seems to only affect what Siri hears and interprets as my app name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key you want is [`CFBundleSpokenName`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW3).

> CFBundleSpokenName
>
> CFBundleSpokenName (String - iOS, macOS) contains a suitable replacement for the app name when performing text-to-speech operations. Include this key in your app bundle when the spelling of your app might be mispronounced by the speech system. For example, if the name of your app is “MyApp123”, you might set the value of this key to “My app one two three”.
>
> This key is supported in iOS 8 and later and in macOS 10.10 and later.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, if I use the name with an Siri intent. It works for Voice over, but if a Siri intent responses, it pronounces the name different. Does anyone have an idea how I could fix this?